# How to get the duration time of each test cases in Cmocka?

Tags: c, xml, unit-testing, cmocka

I was learning how to work with [CMocka](https://cmocka.org/) unit-testing framework in my C project.

So far everything goes well, and I can also generate a HTML report from CMocka's XML output by [junit2html](https://github.com/inorton/junit2html). When I read about what's in the report, I saw that there's an item called "Duration" which was always being zero in each of my test cases. After checking the CMocka XML output file and its source code, I assumed the function of calculating the duration time is not enabled.

In the XML outputfile, every test case showed that `<testcase name="test_MyFunctionName" time="0.000" >`.

In the cmocka.c, I found `HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC` wasn't defined. But even I used `-DHAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC` while compiling, it still not worked.

Besides I found a function called `clock_gettime` (please refer to the code below) and didn't find its definition. Maybe this is the reason why cmocka couldn't calculate the duration time? but how can I use this function?

```
#ifdef HAVE_CLOCK_REALTIME
#define CMOCKA_CLOCK_GETTIME(clock_id, ts) clock_gettime((clock_id), (ts))
#else
#define CMOCKA_CLOCK_GETTIME(clock_id, ts)
#endif
```

Here's my environment and the screenshot of my html test report. Thanks for you time!

- Windows 10
- gcc 9.2.0
- cmocka 1.1.5

[image]

Comment: What does its documentation or tutorials say about these macros? You might need to implement `clock_gettime()` and to define `HAVE_CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: @thebusybee I've check for clock_gettime(), however there's no such a function named like this in cmocka's source code.

Comment: That's why I wrote "_**You** might need to implement ..._".